# Issues With AngularJS Static Progess Bars

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I have a couple of issues with a progress bar I'm trying to do.

My scenario is, on click of a button a progress bar section is displayed (which I have working), this progress bar has 4 separate boxes.  The first one starts to load when the section is displayed (got this bit working also).

My issues are:

1. I cant seem to get it automatically start the next box
2. I also want the bar to change to success once it equals 100

Below is the code in my view please note that only the first `progressbar` has a value set to it

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        Copying Statement Data<br />
        <progressbar id="Statement" value="data.progress" style="margin: 0px 0% !important"></progressbar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        Running Matching Rules<br />
        <progressbar id="Rules" style="margin: 0px 0% !important"></progressbar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        Matching Items<br />
        <progressbar id="Matching" style="margin: 0px 0% !important"></progressbar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        Creating Transactions<br />
        <progressbar id="Transactions" style="margin: 0px 0% !important"></progressbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my controller code which does the animation for me:

```
$scope.commandButtonsDisabled = false;    
$scope.data = { progress: 0 };

    (function progress() {
        if ($scope.data.progress < 100) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.data.progress += 1;
                progress();
            }, 200);
        }
        if ($scope.data.progress == 100) {
            $scope.commandButtonsDisabled = false;
            $scope.showprogbarsection = true;
        }
    })();
```

**Screenshot of progress bars**
[image]

Comment: couple of things to point you in the right direction... Your `Statement` progress bar is the only one which has a `value=`, so it's the only one that will actually display anything.  Second, you have an `if (progress < 100)` but not one for `if (progress = 100)`.

Comment: @Claies I tired to add and if statement but couldn't get it working and I have mentioned that I only have one 'value' in my description.  I'm unsure on how to get it to do multiple which is what I'm asking for help with

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is meant to accomplish; the progress bar just needs to monitor a value that represents where the bar is, percentage wise.  right now, your progress bar is just recursively calling itself every 200 ms and adding one to the value, it's not responding to anything else on the page or to any of the other progress bars.

Comment: *When* are the other progress bars supposed to start filling up? what is supposed to trigger them?

Comment: @Claies Eventually it will call a service which someone else is coding which will have these 4 sections in an each box will progress when it hits them. for know I just want the button to trigger them, then I can tie them up to my service once its built

Comment: so you have one button per progress bar, and you want to hit each button to trigger each bar? or you want one bar to start as soon as the other one finishes? or something else?

Comment: @Claies I have one button and want the next bar to start when the previous bar hits 100 (finishes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
 $scope.data = { progress: 0, progress2: 0, progress3: 0, progress4: 0 };

    (function progress() {
        if ($scope.data.progress < 100) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.data.progress += 1;
                progress();
            }, 100);
        }
        if ($scope.data.progress == 100) {
            (function progress2() {
                if ($scope.data.progress2 < 100) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.data.progress2 += 1;
                        progress2();
                    }, 100);
                }
                if ($scope.data.progress2 == 100) {
                    (function progress3() {
                        if ($scope.data.progress3 < 100) {
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $scope.data.progress3 += 1;
                                progress3();
                            }, 200);
                        }
                        if ($scope.data.progress3 == 100) {
                            (function progress4() {
                                if ($scope.data.progress4 < 100) {
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        $scope.data.progress4 += 1;
                                        progress4();
                                    }, 200);
                                }
                                if ($scope.data.progress4 == 100) {
                                    $scope.disablebutton = false;
                                    $scope.hideprogbarsection = true;
                                }
                            })();
                        }
                    })();
                }
            })();
        }
    })();
```